# RxJava zip with vararg observables

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

When we know exactly how many observables we have with their exact types and we want to zip we do like this

```
Observable<String> data1 = Observable.just("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
Observable<String> data2 = Observable.just("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
Observable<String> data3 = Observable.just("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");

Observable.zip(data1, data2, data3, (a, b, c) -> a + b + c);
```

we use fixed argument functional interface which takes 3 arguments... and it works ok in this case.

but if we know that we have some N number of `Observable<T>` where `T` is the same type how do we zip it? consumer funtion can be something that takes `T...`

but i dont see any way to implement this...

**UPDATE**

Practical problem i'm trying to solve here is that i have some number of `Observable<T>` and i want to forkJoin those and chose only one `T` in the end to emit...

Imagine several observables emiting `T` that i want to take and compare and emit only one with some other observable...

**SOLUTION**

As said in answer there is a zip that takes an iterable and a function, sample code looks like this

```
Observable<String> data1 = Observable.just("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
Observable<String> data2 = Observable.just("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
Observable<String> data3 = Observable.just("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
List<Observable<String>> iter = Arrays.asList(data1, data2, data3);

Observable.zip(iter, args1 -> args1).subscribe((arg)->{
  for (Object o : arg) {
    System.out.println(o);
  }
});
```

which will produce

```
one
one
one
two
two
two
three
three
three
four
four
four
five
five
five
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a zip method which takes an Iterable. That would allow to use n Observables.

Comment: Is there a way to limit zip by time? for example if first two emitted value but more than a second passed it discards current zip and waits for another batch of values... ? in nutshel to make sure all values that arrived were in some specific timeframe...

Comment: @vach That's an interesting question, have you been able to find out if this is possible?

Comment: no but i usually write the custom operators myself and use extension functions of kotlin to make it part of Observable so that  can use them like they are already in the library :)