# RxJava zip with time limitation

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958631/rxjava-zip-with-vararg-observables) i've eventually used a zip(Iterable, Func) to zip variable number of observables using reduce function.

So zip takes 1 emitted value from each passed observable and applyes the function..

How do we limit the time that it will wait for the next observable to emit a value? (if time is passed it shall cancle current zip operation and wait for new batch)

Here is a marbel diagram

```
time  ---|-------|------|------------*------|---|---------->
data1 ---a-------|------a------------*------a---|---------->
data2 ---|----b--|------|--b---------*------|-b-|---------->
data3 ---|------c|------|------------*------|--c|---------->
zip   ---|-------X------|------------*------|---X---------->
```

as you can see first "abc" batch is arriving in timeframe and is successfully getting zipped, but next time "c" in data3 stream gets late and time expires so the entire zip batch waiting for it is discarded...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to apply `timeout()` to the output side of your `zip` operator. The simpler overload will emit a `TimeoutException` which you can either capture in your `Subscriber` or use `retry()` if it is meaningful for your sources to be resubscribed.